# The functioning of derived classes and base classes when they are being implemented into a program

Tags: class, inheritance, superclass, derived-class, base-class

Class `A` is the base class of class `B`. `A` defines a function `test()` and B also defines `test()`.

If `test()` is invoked on an object of class `B`, which version of `test()` will be executed and why?

Comment: What language is that? This seems like homework, and you didn't even put much effort into asking it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then either edit or delete your question.